# Erro ao injetar $state no controller

Tags: angularjs

Estou com um problema ao injetar o `$state` no meu `controller`.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $rootScope,$state){

    $scope.userlogin = "";
    $scope.userkey = "";
    $scope.access = function(){
        console.log("depois")
        //$state.go('home');
    }

});
```

É gerado o seguinte erro (Somente quando incluo o `$state`):

> Error: [$injector:unpr]

Arquivo de rotas:

```
var routerApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$state) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

    $stateProvider

        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'index.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        })


        .state('index', {
            url: '/index',
            templateUrl: 'index.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        });

})
```

---

Boa Tarde. fiz os ajustes porém persiste,

Arquivo de Rotas:

```
var routerApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

    $stateProvider

        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController'
        })


        .state('index', {
            url: '/index',
            templateUrl: 'index.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        });

})
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);


app.controller('HomeController', function($scope,$rootScope,$state){
    console.log('HomeController');

    var nome = "teste";
    var dateAtual = new Date();
    var mensagens = "teste";

    $scope.msg  = mensagens;
    $scope.time = dateAtual;
    $scope.nome = nome;

    console.log(nome);
    console.log(dateAtual);
    console.log(mensagens);
})

// - Este controller sem o $state funciona corretamente.

app.controller('LoginController', function($scope,$rootScope){
    console.log('LOGINCONTROLLER');
});
```

> angular.min.js:118 Error: [$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=%24stateProvider%20%3C-%20%24state%20%3C-%20HomeController

Comment: Amigo seu .state('login' esta apontando para o controller HomeController, deveria estar apontando para o LoginController.

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta.

Comment: mBiz, se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, não esqueça de marcar como resolvido (o ícone de "check" ao lado da resposta). =D

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você está fazendo a injeção do `$state` no arquivo de configuração, o que não é permitido. Remova ele, deixando sua linha assim:

```
routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
```

E o problema deve ser resolvido.

---

### Editado:

Baseado na sua edição, o problema é que você está definindo os módulos de modo errado.

Apenas para esclarecer, para você criar um módulo, deve usar o seguinte código:

```
angular.module('meuModulo', []);
```

Se você deseja usar o mesmo módulo para diversos `controllers`, deve usar sempre o mesmo módulo, porém sem `[]`. Assim:

```
angular.module('meuModulo').config(...
angular.module('meuModulo').controller(...
```

É nisso que você está errando, pois você está criando 1 módulo para a configuração e outro módulo para o `controller`.

```
var routerApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

O que você pode fazer é assim:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []); //Cria somente 1 módulo

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {...
app.controller('LoginController',...
```

---

Outro ponto importante que notei agora e acredito que você não esteja fazendo.

Para poder usar o sistema de rotas através do `.state` você precisa instalar o módulo [uiRouter](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) antes. Então seu código final deve ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']); //Cria somente 1 módulo

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {...
app.controller('LoginController',...

<script src="angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script> //Altere o src para o caminho onde você salvar o script do uiRouter
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!
Problema resolvido e $state passou a ser reconhecido sem problemas. Abraços.